# How to get the executable out of a compiled function and run it in cmd

Tags: compile, interoperability

Can someone please guide how to run the function compiled by Wolfram Language in `cmd` independent of the kernel. It seems to export it into `"Assembler"`, `"Binary"`, `"LLVM"` and `"LLVMBinary"`. How can I get a standalone executable in windows 10 from any of these format?

From any of these 4 format will do especially if it can be done natively without installing any other program.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompileExport.html

Please use the example in the documentation for illustration.

```
FunctionCompileExport[..., Function[Typed[arg, "MachineInteger"], arg + 1]]
```

Comment: Good question! I am also curious as this is a version 12 question and version 12 seems to be out only for selected users and for Wolfram Online at the moment... So, it may take some time for this to be answered.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Sure. Version 12 is officially out on coming `Tuesday`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's good to know!